# scene size vs pane size

Tags: java, javafx, pane

I was wondering that in Javafx, can you set the scene size and the pane size separately and independently(assuming that there's going to be only one pane in the entire scene)? for example, making the scene with 100width and 100height with a plain pane inside it with 50width and 50height? Or does the size of the pane always depend on the size of the scene? also when I use my mouse and change the size of the popup window(which will then, change the size of the scene), would that also automatically change the size of the pane? or is it that in some cases, if I change the scene size from 100x100 to 300x300 by dragging with my mouse, the pane size could just remain 50x50?

Comment: The size of the client area of a `Window` determines the scene size which determines the size of the scene's root node. Unless you set the size explicitly the initial scene size is determined based on the pref size of the root and the window size is chosen that allows the window to contain the scene. (of course screen size is also considered to determine an upper bound on the window size).

Comment: Thanks but I'm still wondering if I can set the size of the pane and scene separately and independently. also I've never seen any code that sets the size of the pane . Every piece of code that I've seen only sets the size of the scene by doing 'Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);

Comment: The only place where the size of `Region`s is really set is in the `layoutChildren` method of the `Parent`. Outside of the method you only set the constraints (`min`/`max`/`pref` sizes)

Comment: what do you mean by 'the size of Regions'? you mean the size of the pane? so basically, you're saying that there's no way to set the size of the pane directly ?(and that's why everyone types 'Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);'?

Comment: `Pane` extends `Region`. You can do `root.setPrefSize(300, 300);` but you cannot be sure the exact size will be 300x300 since those values could be ignored in favor of constraints that have "higher precedence" such as the size of the scene being explicitly set to a different size.